# Subset a dataframe by matching it to a list and include non-match value too in the output using R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe (`myDF`) that has 2 columns "A" and "B" and a function (`myfunc`) which takes a list as an input and if it finds a match in column "A" then it returns a new dataframe that is a subset of myDF containing the value match and the corresponding "B" column.

But I want the function to also return the non-matching value in column A and NULL string in column B.

`myDF`:

```
A  B
1 11
2 22
3 33
```

`myfunc`:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
  r<- with(myDF, myDF[a %in% x, c("a", "b")])
  return(data.frame(r))
}
```

Input: `mylist` = `c(1,2,"E")`

Expected Output:

```
A      B
1     11
2     22
E   NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a logical index and assign

```
i1 <- with(myDF, !A %in% mylist)
myDF$B[i1] <- "NULL"
myDF$A[i1] <- mylist[i1]
myDF
#  A    B
#1 1   11
#2 2   22
#3 E NULL
```

Note:  By assigning a character string to 'B' column, it effectively changes the type from `numeric` to `character`.  A better option would be to assign it to `NA`

```
myDF$B[i1] <- NA
```

Or

```
data.frame(A= mylist, B = myDF$B[match(mylist, myDF$A)])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a join operation, which can be done in base R with `merge`, if you make the list a `data.frame` first. The `all.y = T` argument includes rows of `mylistDF` with no matching rows in `myDF` in the output.

```
mylistDF <- data.frame(A = mylist, stringsAsFactors = F)

merge(myDF, mylistDF, by = 'A', all.y = T)

#   A  B
# 1 1 11
# 2 2 22
# 3 E NA
```

Since you tagged `tidyr`, here's a `tidyverse` solution (same output)

```
library(tidyverse)

mylistDF <- tibble(A = mylist)

myDF %>% 
  mutate_at('A', as.character) %>% 
  right_join(mylistDF, by = 'A')
```